# Отправляются пакеты RA вместо SA

Tags: ubuntu, http, tcp, wireshark

Я новичок в этом деле, так что заранее прошу прощения за возможные глупые ошибки. Я связал две вирт машины (VM Vbox) с помощью сетевого моста, решил проверить как устанавливается соединение между ними, отправил пакет с SYN на 80 порт, в ответ получаю пакет с RA[image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Прочитал, что это происходит из-за закрытых портов, поэтому попытался их открыть с помощью `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` и `sudo ufw allow 80`, но ничего не меняется, и при сканировании портов через `nmap` они все были закрыты, хотя вот что показывает `ufw`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего такое может происходить и как можно это подправить?

Answer (score 0):

На 80-м порту никто не слушает.
Запустите HTTP-сервер.

Comment: `ss -ltn | grep 80` Для проверки этого варианта.